# Wiring bathroom exhaust

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

[image]

Having trouble wiring my fan to work with the switch. It either constantly runs or just doesn’t. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which cable, black & white , is the feed?  Is there a socket that gets wired into this?

Comment: When you hooked it up your way, did turning on the switch blow the breaker? *Don't try it*

Comment: @Harper it did blow the breaker. Twice lol

Comment: @JACK I honestly haven’t the foggiest idea which is the feed. If by socket you mean light switch, then yes.

Comment: Thank you all for replying. Honestly the only help I’ve found. I’ve called every electrician in my tristate and either they’re busy or don’t call me back. One told me it would be a waste of time to come out my way because it’s not a big enough job. Genuinely I’m very grateful for the input and help.

Comment: I understand the electricians statement, this is very simple to us and is a 5 minute job but driving to your location and back will take time and folks get upset when we can fix something in a few minutes and charge 75-100$  so we usually only do these tiny jobs for good friends and family.  Even in this case there’s no up vote so although very easy for an electrician trying to put it in terms of the question was not worth the time so you can see why no one wants these jobs.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cable will be the feeder (hot and neutral) and one cable will go to the switch. The one that ran all the time will be your supply the other the cable to the switch. 
Turn the breaker off and verify it is off.
Tie the white on the cable that made it run all the time to the white on the fan. The black on the fan goes to the black on the cable that did nothing, the black on the cable that made it run all the time to the white that did nothing.  Now wrap some black tape on that white wire connected to the black. 
To do everything correctly the white wire at the switch should have some tape also. 
Turn the breaker on and now the switch should work .
This is a switch leg the white is always hot and should be reidentified as a hot, I said traps but tape or fingernail polish, paint any color but white green or gray would be code compliant.

Comment: To ensure that it is in fact a switch loop, see if the non-supply wires get shorted together when you turn on the fan at the switch.

Comment: @ratchet freak. Ok I’m not sure what non supply wire means but I’m gonna do some research. & then I’ll do that. Thank you

Comment: I meant the wires going to the switch. The wires that aren't the hot and neutral from the supply.